# Почему возникает ошибка при установке gulp-sass?

Tags: gulp, sass, npm

Пытаюсь установить сборку gulp себе на диск, клонировал из репозитория, запускаю `npm install`, и выдаёт ошибку:

> "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe. - Unexpected token
>   P"

Sublime Text стоит редактором по умолчанию. В пользовательской переменной EDITOR находится путь, который указан в тексте ошибки. Как это можно исправить, и почему нода ругается на путь?

Comment: а ты где команду `npm install` выполняешь? Существует ли `npm` в переменных средах, и правильный ли у неё путь? И если можно скриншот консоли. Или запиши полностью результат в файлик

Comment: http://pixs.ru/showimage/2016051118_8782905_21893899.png

Comment: В переменной PATH прописан правильный путь к npm

Comment: в `\node_modules\npmconf\npmconf.js` на 363 строчке посмотрите, что приходит в `f` вызвав `console.log(f)` и запустив `npm i` заново

Comment: папка npmconf и всё её содержимое генерируется при запуске npm i, а потом - удаляется

Comment: У тебя кстати 2 одинаковых пути до `npm`. Но я не знаю в чем может быть твоя проблема. Откуда берется этот путь. Можешь попробовать что то в этом духе http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851908/ https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/640

Comment: Кстати говоря, в путях у тебя нет ссылки на `windows\system32`, что страно

Comment: Я прописал путь до System32 в  системную переменную PATH, сначала в конец, затем в начало. Безрезультатно

Comment: А консоль при этом перезагружал? Когда вносишь изменения в переменные среды, надо перезагружать данные (т.е. заного запускать консоль)

Comment: Только что перезагрузил консоль, выполнил npm i. Теперь ругается на букву S в пути :)  http://pixs.ru/showimage/2016051119_5576102_21894665.png

Comment: Прописал в пути до Саблайма везде двойные обратные слеши, и заработало. только теперь вылезла другая ошибка.http://pixs.ru/showimage/2016051119_8903366_21894787.png. Благодарю за помощь)))

Comment: модуль `node-gyp` не установлен. `npm i --save-dev node-gyp`